# How to copy Dropbox file link from Dropbox folder using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dropbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwmfF.png)
I use Dropbox folder by setup Dropbox program in my computer
When I have to get direct link to any file in Dropbox folder just I go to Dropbox folder in my computer and choose that file and right click by mouse and select copy direct link of that file

How I do that by vb.net 
 I want to brows for file and select it and get that direct link by vb.net

And I am sorry for my bad English

Comment: it's impossible ?

Answer (score 0):

[Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Discuss-Developer-API/How-do-I-get-the-share-url-of-a-local-dropbox-file-using-vb-net/m-p/345339 ]

The kind of Dropbox link you're referring to isn't a "direct" link, but rather a "shared" link, where the link itself points to an HTML preview page, where the user can download the file if they want. You can find information on this feature here:

https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/view-only-access

Dropbox does offer an API you can use for listing, uploading, downloading, and sharing files, among other operations. You can find everything you need to get started with the Dropbox API, including documentation, tutorials, and SDKs here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers

Dropbox does offer a .NET SDK in particular:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet

To create a shared link for a file or folder using the .NET SDK, you would use the `CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync` method:

https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Sharing_Routes_SharingUserRoutes_CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync_1.htm

Comment: Hello My friends i use tht function CreateSharedLinkAsync  but i have error

Comment: Me.TextBox2.Text = CreateSharedLinkAsync(NewPicturePath.Text, False, Nothing)

Comment: The `CreateSharedLinkAsync` method gives you a `PathLinkMetadata`, not a `String`, but you're attempting to use it as a `String`. By the way, I accidentally linked to the deprecated version of this method. You should actually use `CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync`. I fixed it in my answer. That returns a `SharedLinkMetadata`. You can get the shared link from [`SharedLinkMetadata.Url`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/P_Dropbox_Api_Sharing_SharedLinkMetadata_Url.htm).

Comment: my dear friend, I am so sorry 
look to that error https://6.top4top.net/p_1237rbllw1.png how i do it

Comment: It looks like you're stuck on supplying the `settings` parameter. That parameter is actually optional, so you can skip it if you don't need to set any non-default settings. I believe you'd need to use named parameters to do that, like `CreateSharedLinkWithSettingsAsync(path:Me.NewPicturePath.Text)`. (Otherwise, the `settings` parameter should be an instance of [`SharedLinkSettings`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/T_Dropbox_Api_Sharing_SharedLinkSettings.htm).)

Comment: i lost my hope look i cant understand what i have to do ? https://6.top4top.net/p_1237fhfr81.png

Comment: The parameter name is `path`, not `Path`. Please try `path` as in my previous comment.

Comment: when i write  path it converted Automatically to Path and i cant change it ? i am  so sorry my friend be patient to help me Plz